# What is consuming my Google Drive space?

Tags: google-drive

I'm confused. Google Drive app says I consume 5 GB of space, yet the folder on my computer is merely 90 MB big.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're sharing storage amongst Google Drive, Gmail, and Google+ Photos.

Go to [the web interface](https://drive.google.com/) and hover your mouse pointer and you'll get a breakdown of what's using your storage:

[image: Storage quick view]

Click the link and you'll get some more details:

[image: Google Storage used]

As you can see, this matches up with what the Google Drive app is reporting:

[image: Google Drive app storage]

Comment: You were right--photos and emails took up 4.9 GB