# Google Drive says I'm out of space, but I don't appear to be

Tags: google-drive

I can't figure out how to solve this.  GDrive says I'm out of space - WAY OUT OF SPACE.  As in, 44.6GB out of 15GB used.  This can only be because I had a ~40GB iPhoto Library that got backed up because it happened about a day after that backup started.  My understanding was that those photos would not count towards my quota, but regardless I went ahead and deleted it, and all the photos it had backed up from my phone, and yes I emptied the trash days ago.  But it still says I'm completely, massively out of space.

How can I get back to under 15GB as I was before this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is consuming my Google Drive space?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/68991/what-is-consuming-my-google-drive-space)

Comment: Nope not at all.  As far as I can see there is nothing consuming the space.  I can't see any reason why GDrive apparently refuses to recognize that I deleted the largest file(s).  Also, Drive does not display the allocation when hovering as indicated in that answer (at least it doesn't for me in Chrome).  I'm guessing it was a feature that is no longer implemented.

Comment: Error 404...  D'oh...

Comment: Check this https://one.google.com/storage (only works for consumer accounts)

Comment: Aha!  That worked.  But it says 41.48GB is from Google Photos.  I thought those weren't supposed to count against your storage?  Also there seems to be no way to delete multiple photos from Google Photos' web interface (which I never new existed until now).

Comment: They are counting because it's very likely that they were upload as "original quality" (or something like that) instead as "high quality"

Comment: So I see... I believed I was set to High Quality mode but apparently not.  Thankfully they give an option to compress everything and reclaim the space.  If you care to make an answer about the high quality option, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that the photos are counting against your storage quota because, due to some reason, they were upload as "original quality" (or something like that) instead as "high quality"

If you have a free/consumer account you could check what app is using the storage quota in https://one.google.com/storage

NOTE: The above link only works for consumer accounts.